# Python For loop taking too much time

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I'm having two different datasets where one of them contains 650k records and another contains 20k records and I want to find matching or approximately matching data in a single column of both datasets. How to speed up the process, as Python is very slow?

Note: My data type is string in both columns of two datasets.

Here is my simple code:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df1
df2
    
for i in df1['string1']:
   for j in df2['string2']:
      Ratio = fuzz.ratio(i.lower(),j.lower())
print(Ratio)
```

Comment: If you need to compare every entry to every other entry then this is a task of fixed complexity, and cannot be made any more efficient as a single process. Your best option is to split `df1` and `df2` into lots of smaller sets, and then run the comparisons in parallel. `multiprocessing` `pool` is probably a good starting point for this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to replace your usage of FuzzyWuzzy with [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) (I am the author), which is significantly faster.
Using RapidFuzz your algorithm can be implemented in the following way:

```py
import pandas as pd
from rapidfuzz import fuzz, process

def lower(str, **kwargs):
    return str.lower()

d = {'string1': ["abcd", "abcde"]*1000, 'string2': ["abcd", "abc"]*1000}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
process.cdist(df["string1"], df["string2"],
    processor=lower, scorer=fuzz.ratio)
```

which returns

```
array([[100,  86, 100, ...,  86, 100,  86],
       [ 89,  75,  89, ...,  75,  89,  75],
       [100,  86, 100, ...,  86, 100,  86],
       ...,
       [ 89,  75,  89, ...,  75,  89,  75],
       [100,  86, 100, ...,  86, 100,  86],
       [ 89,  75,  89, ...,  75,  89,  75]], dtype=uint8)
```

You can further improve the performance using multithreading:

```py
process.cdist(df["string1"], df["string2"],
    processor=lower, scorer=fuzz.ratio, workers=-1)
```

In case you do not want to use all available cores you can specifiy a different count for `workers`.